# If $f$ is a real valued function and $f(x)/x > f'(x)$ for all $x$, then f is concave.

Tags: calculus

Show that if $f$ is a real valued function and $$\frac{f(x)}{x}>f'(x)$$ for all x, then $f$ is concave.
And the definition of concave given is $$f({\lambda}x+(1-\lambda)y)\ge{\lambda}f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$ for all x and y.

And the hint is "using Taylor series", but I am not sure if I can use $f(x)$ is close to $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$.

I start with the inequality given and the approximation above but eventually it leads to a very complicated one.
Can anyone help me with this? How should I choose a or I use the wrong approximation?

(I am sorry that where the function is defined is not mentioned clearly since this is actually from a microeconomic course, I think the function is just well behaved enough for us to discuss the condition.)

Comment: If I have not made a mistake, on $]0,+\infty[$, the function $f(x)=x\exp(-x)$ is such that $\exp(-x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}>f^{\prime}(x)=(1-x)\exp(-x)$. But this function is not concave as for $x=2,y=6, \lambda =1/2$, the inequality $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ is $\displaystyle 4\exp(-4)\geq \frac{2\exp(-2)+6\exp(-6)}{2}$  and this is not true

Comment: Even worse, consider $f(x) = 1/x$, in that case $f(x)/x = 1/x^2 > -1/x^2 = f'(x)$. This despite the fact that $f(x) = 1/x$ is *convex* and not concave anywhere.